# Show StackExchange Questions in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, stackexchange

How can I have the questions I've asked across the StackExchange network show up on a Wordpress blog? The end result would be something similar to having Twitter tweets show up on a blog.

Comment: I'm nominating this for reopening. I think it's a real question, since barring my answer, I couldn't find a consolidated feed of all my own questions/answers across all the StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

Get a plugin like [RSSImport](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rss-import/) and plug [your user feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/1417894) into it.

**Update**
After some trial and error, I got this consolidated feed of all your accounts' feeds going for you on Yahoo! Pipes: [Chernoff's StackExchange](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=9accb3fd07e080d601ffd3196c21a021&_render=rss)

Comment: Note: so far I haven't found an easy way to combine all your questions / answers across the networks...I'll update my answer if I do.

Comment: Right now I'm doing as you described, which works, but this way I have to add an RSS feed for each of my stack accounts.